# Performance testing tool suggestion for Node.js and ASP.NET

Tags: performance, load-testing

I am to carry out performance tests on [Node.js](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) and .NET. This is an academic exercise. I have searched on Google for performance testing tools, and I came across such tools as [HP LoadRunner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_LoadRunner), and [Apache JMeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_JMeter).

What is the best tool I can use to perform these tests (that is, load testing, stress testing, CPU usage, etc., for both Node.js and [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET))?

Do I use the same tool for testing both platforms or a different tool for each platform?

Comment: welcome to SQA.  You may want to clairify what exactly you are trying to accomplish with these tests, the more detail you can provide the better answers you will get.  I would also consider separating your last question "Do I use the same tool for testing..." into a second question.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SQA, ykel.  If you are focused on testing an HTTP server, the language/framework used to build the server doesn't particularly matter, so the same tool should work with both.  (Possible exception: some server frameworks make it easy to collect and server up performance metrics, e.g. queue lengths or some kind of counters, and some performance tools may make it easier/harder to get at those metrics.)

Possibly more relevant is whether you're trying to test (1) loading the same page over and over again or (2) serving up a variety of pages associated with one or more workflows.  There are lots of well-crafted tools for the former; see for example the tools listed on [this page](http://www.linuxlinks.com/article/20121116094525476/WebServerPerformanceTools.html).  For the latter, you will end up writing scripts (or data files) to drive the workflows, and the available tools will differentiate themselves in terms of their scripting capabilities.

Load Runner, JMeter, and [The Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/) can all deal with workflows.

Comment: The tests I need  to perform are load testing, stress tests, cpu usage, hit time. I came across webload tester, would you recommend this?

Comment: The tests I need to perform are load testing, stress tests, hits persecond, pages persecond,cpu usage, hit time. I came across a tool called "webload" tester, is it a right tool for my testing scenario? could you recommend any material or guide for carrying out these tests? thanks

Comment: Sorry, your answer is orthogonal to whether you're testing (1) or (2) (second paragraph of my answer).

Comment: thanks, this means I will need more than one tool if I am correct, is there any open source tools you could recommend please (sorry for such basic questions, my first time on performance testing), I understand JMeter is opensource,  thanks